# How to change IP in the hosts file

Tags: operating-system, hosts

I am trying to change the IP address set to a particular site in the host file.
For example :

```
# 123.123.123   www.google.com
# 456.456.456   www.google.com
```

I want to make a test that I enter Google through `123.123.123` and as the program changes and open Google through `456.456.456`.

Changing the servers manually is removing the # from the beginning of the line.
I do not want to use selenium grid with some machines since any machine on another server do not have the resources for it.

I want to change this in the same machine while running through the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: I'm not looking for someone to write me a code ..
I'm looking for a work method

Answer (score 0):

As the `etc/hosts` file is picked up immediately by the system without a restart you can manipulate or even completely overwrite this file during your run.

The trouble is that to edit the hosts file you need 'root' rights and you are actually changing the behaviour of your host system. In order to prevent this you might think about running in a docker environment but if that is not possible you can do something like this with root access:

`/etc/hosts` file

```
# 123.123.123   www.google.com
# 456.456.456   www.google.com
```

as part of your test run:

```
# at start of run
sed -i .bak 's/# 123.123.123/123.123.123/g' /etc/hosts

# do other tests now

# later when stuff has changed
sed -i .bak 's/123.123.123/456.456.456/g' /etc/hosts
```

Something like this?

Comment: Thank you to the respondents
What I did was I deleted the file and rewrote it while running, like  your advice
Thanks

Comment: My pleasure. Mostly on this site appreciation is shown by upvoting :-)